# Redirection from a query string to a path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm currently in the process of updating a legacy app's frontend which used query parameters as a "path". (Ex: `?greeting=hello` instead of `/greeting/hello`)

However moving forward we want to transition to path-based routing, with redirection from the legacy query structure.

Preferably I would've liked to do something like this:

`<Redirect from="?gameid=:game" to="/game/:game" />`

However it doesn't seem to be as straightforward as that since react-router does not provide support for query params ([#209](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/209%20#209)).

What's the cleanest way to solve this?

URL manipulation with plain JS has been proven to be quite error-prone in combination with react.

Comment: You could try checking for this.props.location.query in componentDidMount and do a redirect there, e.g. `if (this.props.location.query.gameid)`

Comment: Alternatively, you can check out the onEnter method of a route, which allows access to nextState.location.query params, and the replace method to navigate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my situation was one that was quite an edge case and thus not handled well by react-router.

Since the app uses a hash-based history (`/#/path`), query parameters would simply not be catched if they weren't preceded by a hash in `onEnter`'s `nextState`.

What I ended up doing was handling any possible queries inside of an `IndexRouter`.

```
<IndexRoute component={LoginPage}
  onEnter={
    (nextState, replaceWith) => {
      console.log(nextState);
      var obj = qs.parse(document.location.search.split("").slice(1,document.location.search.split("").length).join(""));
      if(obj.gameid){
        document.location.href = document.location.origin + document.location.pathname + "#/game/" + obj.gameid;
      }
    }
  }
/>
```

This way seems preferable to putting routing logic inside a container app's `componentDidMount` since routing logic actually belongs inside of a `Route`. It also ensures all subsequent calls *will* be handled properly.

Kudos to /u/mrkre for pointing me in the direction of onEnter.